# getting low fps and animation is blurred in rendered setting

Tags: modeling, animation, lighting, frame-rate

[image]

https://blend-exchange.com/b/JK6JOMER/

okay...so i have my fps set to 30 for my animation intentionally...however i am getting 17-25 fps drops as well as blurred animation. i have a 165 hz curved monitor running on a nividia rtx 2070.
i can share the blend file if anyone wants to look at it. i dont know why its doing this and i need help.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=JK6JOMER" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/JK6JOMER/)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.